# copy values under conditions to a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Daily, I add a row to the sheet, (using onEdit() and I *timestamp* it - *this function is not shown here)* 
Problem occurs at the end.

Please see below :

[First sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZrAl.png)

My purpose is to copy values to another sheet called "Payment", choosing one type of payment : PPAL, CASH, or others. (PPAL in this example)

```
function typesOfPayment() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("John");
var rows = ss.getMaxRows();// *because I add a line per day, on the top*
var columns = ss.getMaxColumns();// *I probably never will add columns...*
var values = ss.getRange(1,1,rows,columns).getValues();
var target = new Array();

     for(i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
        if (values[i][2]=="PPAL"){ // *if condition is true copy the whole row to target*
        target.push(values[i]);// *copy the whole row*
        }  
     }

var sDest=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Payment");
sDest.getRange(1,1,rows,columns).setValues(target); 
}
```

I get a final error message : "0 was specified, but waiting for 8". 
The var rows seems wrong ?

I am lost. What to do ?

Thanks for your help.
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points :

1. The index of array starts from 0. So the index of column with `PPAL` is 1.
2. The numbers of rows and colums for `getRange()` which is used at `setValues()` are the size of `target` which is used at `setValues()`.

When these are reflected to your script, the modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function typesOfPayment() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("John");
  var rows = ss.getMaxRows();// *because I add a line per day, on the top*
  var columns = ss.getMaxColumns();// *I probably never will add columns...*
  var values = ss.getRange(1,1,rows,columns).getValues();
  var target = new Array();
  for(i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
    if (values[i][1]=="PPAL"){ // *if condition is true copy the whole row to target*
      target.push(values[i]);// *copy the whole row*
    }  
  }
  var sDest=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Payment");
  sDest.getRange(1,1,target.length,target[0].length).setValues(target); 
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Perfect, it works! I understand the mistakes. Thanks fot this quick answer!

Comment: @Eric There is a check button at the upper left of my answer. The button can be pushed by only owner of the question. Before pushing the accept button, you can see as a semitransparent button.

Comment: Thanks again. Done!